# what's the function of $this->getCanViewOrder() in success.phtml in magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out what the following function is checking:

```
  <?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()) :?>

 <?php echo $this->__('<strong><a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">Click here to print</a></strong> an invoice or a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
```

In the `success.phtml` file in Magento the "Click here to print" link doesn't show anymore on the thank you page. Where is this function located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I revised this answer greatly after doing a bit more research.

---

For the record, it looks like `getCanPrintOrder` is one of Magento's magic methods for getting object data. You'd set its value with `setCanPrintOrder`, and if you haven't called that before, `getCanPrintOrder` will just return `null`. You could also set it by calling `setData('can_print_order')`.

It looks like the only place it's being set is in the Onepage checkout success block, `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success`, in the `_prepareLastOrder` method:

```
protected function _prepareLastOrder()
{
    $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    if ($orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if ($order->getId()) {
            $isVisible = !in_array($order->getState(),
                Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getInvisibleOnFrontStates());
            $this->addData(array(
                'is_order_visible' => $isVisible,
                'view_order_id' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/view/', array('order_id' => $orderId)),
                'print_url' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/print', array('order_id'=> $orderId)),
                'can_print_order' => $isVisible,
                'can_view_order'  => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $isVisible,
                'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId(),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called from the `_beforeToHtml` method, which would be called when that page is rendered.

Pulling the string a bit further, we see that the `can_print_order` is determined by the `$isVisible` variable, and that's set by this line:

```
$isVisible = !in_array($order->getState(),
    Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getInvisibleOnFrontStates());
```

It's checking if the order state is one of the states that are visible on front. These are ultimately set in the `config.xml` file for the core Magento sales module.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <states>
                    <new translate="label">
                        <label>New</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </new>
                    ...
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

All of the states are visible_on_front by default, so unless you've changed them, or something has overridden them, that shouldn't be your problem. I'd double-check this by dumping the value of `getCanPrintOrder` in success.phtml.

A hacky workaround would be overriding the template file and adding

```
$this->setCanPrintOrder(true);
$this->setCanViewOrder(true);
```

Anywhere above the if condition. Or just removing the checks altogether.